# elixir: find out the reason of process termination

Tags: process, elixir, signals, amqp, gen-server

During performance test my application died with following log:

```
17:17:28.187 [info]  SIGTERM received - shutting down

17:17:28.187 [info] SIGTERM received - shutting down

17:17:28.188 [error] GenServer #PID<0.3707.0> terminating
** (stop) 'stopping because dependent process <0.3703.0> died: shutdown'
Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.3703.0>, :shutdown}
17:17:28.189 [error] gen_server <0.3707.0> terminated with reason: "stopping because dependent process <0.3703.0> died: shutdown"
17:17:28.190 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.3707.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: "stopping because dependent process <0.3703.0> died: shutdown" in gen_server:handle_common_reply/8 line 751
17:17:28.190 [error] Supervisor {<0.3705.0>,amqp_connection_sup} had child connection started with amqp_gen_connection:start_link(<0.3706.0>, {amqp_params_network,<<"publicmq-npperfcom1">>,<<"publicmq-npperfcom1">>,<<"/publicmq-npperfcom1">>,...}) at <0.3707.0> exit with reason "stopping because dependent process <0.3703.0> died: shutdown" in context child_terminated
17:17:28.190 [error] Supervisor {<0.3705.0>,amqp_connection_sup} had child connection started with amqp_gen_connection:start_link(<0.3706.0>, {amqp_params_network,<<"publicmq-npperfcom1">>,<<"publicmq-npperfcom1">>,<<"/publicmq-npperfcom1">>,...}) at <0.3707.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
```

Code that spawn connection to amqp looks like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Events.AmqpTransport do

  require Logger
  use GenServer
  use AMQP

  @restart_delay 2000 # 2 seconds

  defmodule State do
    @moduledoc false
    @type t :: %__MODULE__{
      exchange: String.t,
      channel: AMQP.Channel.t,
      routing_key: String.t,
      emitter_id: String.t,
      np_tracking_id: String.t
    }
    defstruct [:exchange, :channel, :routing_key, :emitter_id, :np_tracking_id]
  end

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(_opts) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    send(self(), :connect)
    {:ok, nil}
  end

  def handle_info(:connect, _state) do
    username = get_conf(:username)
    password = get_conf(:password)
    host = get_conf(:host)
    port = get_conf(:port)
    vhost = String.replace(get_conf(:vhost), "/", "%2f")
    amqp_url = "amqp://#{username}:#{password}@#{host}:#{port}/#{vhost}"
    Logger.info("amqp transport connecting to #{amqp_url}")
    case Connection.open(amqp_url) do
      {:ok, conn} ->
        Process.link(conn.pid)
        {:ok, chan} = Channel.open(conn)
        :ok = AMQP.Exchange.declare(chan, get_conf(:exchange), :topic, durable: true)
        state = %State{
          exchange: get_conf(:exchange),
          channel: chan,
          routing_key: get_conf(:routing_key),
          emitter_id: Application.fetch_env!(:coups_events, :emitter_id),
          np_tracking_id: Application.fetch_env!(:coups_events, :np_tracking_id),
        }
        {:noreply, state}
      {:error, err} ->
        Logger.error("amqp transport failed\n Err: #{inspect(err)}\n Retrying to connect ...")
        Process.send_after(self(), :connect, @restart_delay)
        {:noreply, nil}
    end
  end

  def handle_info({:EXIT, pid, reason}, _state) do
    Logger.error("amqp transport failed with #{inspect(reason)}")
    Process.unlink(pid)
    Process.send_after(self(), :connect, @restart_delay)
    {:noreply, nil}
  end

  def handle_cast({:emit, event}, state) do
    # event publishing
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp get_conf(key) do
    conf = Application.get_env(:events, :amqp)
    conf[key]
  end
end
```

Questions:

1. AmqpTransport didn't trap exit. Why?
2. In error log I see pids. Can I see named processes there?
3. What could happened there to make process die? How can I investigate details further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Connection` starts supervised internally by `amqp` application’s supervisor as [`amqp_sup:start_connection_sup(AmqpParams3)`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang-client/blob/master/src/amqp_connection.erl#L173) (`Connection.open/2` simply delegates to [`:amqp_connection.start/2`](https://github.com/pma/amqp/blob/v1.6.0/lib/amqp/connection.ex#L157)) under the hood.

That is tricky and not idempotent in general to have one process to be linked to two processes trapping exits, that’s why the [official documentation suggests](https://hexdocs.pm/amqp/readme.html#stable-rabbitmq-connection) to `Process.monitor/1` the underlying connection and go full path restarting the monitoring process as well.

I recall there were [complaints](https://twitter.com/whatyouhide/status/1329182911506092032?s=20) from  Andrea Leopardi on the relevant topic, but it always worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Hi sorry to comment in here @Aleksei, but can you give me some lead in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148306/how-to-make-a-genserver-to-run-with-a-frequency-value-elixir